# Query List of Maps in DynamoDB

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, subquery, nosql

I am trying to filter list of maps from a dynamodb table which is of the following format.

```
{
   id: "Number",
   users: {
      { userEmail: abc@gmail.com, age:"23" },
      { userEmail: de@gmail.com, age:"41" }
   }
}
```

I need to get the data of the user with userEmail as "abc@gmail.com". Currently I am doing it using the following dynamodb query. Is there any another efficient way to solve this issue ?

```
 var params = {
        TableName: 'users',
        Key:{
            'id': id
        }
  };
  var docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();
  docClient.get(params, function (err, data) {
    if (!err) {
      const users = data.Item.users;
      const user = users.filter(function (user) {
        return user.email == userEmail; 
      });   
      // filtered has the required user in it
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

The only way you can get a single item in dynamo by id if you have a table with a partition key. So you need to have a table that looks like:

**Email** (string) - partition key

**Id** (some-type) - user id

...other relevant user data

Unfortunately, since a nested field cannot be a partition key you will have to maintain a separate table here and won't be able to use an index in DynamoDB (neither LSI, nor GSI).

It's a common pattern in NoSQL to duplicate data, so there is nothing unusual in it. If you were using Java, you could use [transactions library](https://github.com/awslabs/dynamodb-transactions), to ensure that both tables are in sync.

If you are not going to use Java you could read [DynamoDB stream](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Streams.html) of the original database (where emails are nested fields) and update the new table (where emails are partition keys) when an original table is updated.